# How to fix AutoCAD/Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003, autocad

I have a user who has a AutoCAD (2010) drawing in a Word (2003) document.

Double clicking on the AutoCAD drawing in a Word doc, AutoCAD has the following error:

> A10 Drawing Recovery In your previous work session, the program terminated unexpectedly.  You can restore unsaved changes from a backup file by using the Drawing Recovery Manager.

and doesn't open all the tool bars and freezes.

The drawing appears in AutoCAD but freezes, can't click on anything it beeps, I have to use Task Manager to close AutoCAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never dealt with AutoCAD dwg in Word, and this is NOT strictly an AutoCAD question, but I am going to try to help.
When AutoCAD "almost opens the drawing, but freezes", usually
1-- drawing is corrupt.
2-- drawing has a few complications or errors, which make it "too much for the computer to figure out" at the same time you are opening the program. (which is why we open AutoCAD first).
Of course, if the drawing were created in-house, you could simply go to the .bak file and re-name it.
If the drawing opened previously from Word, there might still be a temp file. 
If the drawing was emailed to you before the user put it into Word, do you still have the email?
ETC
Too much info missing - but I am trying to put in clues for you.
If you still can't open it, please write back with ALL details and I will try to assist.
  See if the following article would help:
https://getsatisfaction.com/autocad360/topics/problem-opening-dwg-files
Good luck!